# how to avoid background-color flash while loading up a web page?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a website (using PHP). The main background is of green color and content area is of white. While switching to one page to another (as it takes a few milliseconds) the background color gives a flash before the white takes it over. I think its because of the way the dom element being drawn/created. I tried using `ob_start();` and `ob_flush();` but not much of a help.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks
JJ

Comment: Sounds like the issue is browser side and may be the way you've constructed your HTML/CSS.

Which browser and version are you using?  Can you post a snippet of the minimum HTML required to reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

You might try explicitly setting a size (height and width) or min-height for the content area. You can also use a background image that has the white area. If your background is a solid color (or a horizontal gradient), you can use a 1px high gif that would be a very small file size. But you still might have a blink before the background loaded the first time.

Ultimately, I think users are used to seeing this. I don't think it's a big problem and wouldn't spend a lot of time trying to solve it. But maybe your boss disagrees.

Comment: you hit it on the head .. boss disagrees. let me check about setting height. thx

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but in your CSS, put the two rules in one CSS file, then the content area style declaration first, and make sure this CSS file loads before any others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the case, but I saw that to avoid the flickering problem of not stylized elements in IE, somebody added an empty script tag as

```
<script type="text/javascript">//This is necessary to avoid flickering of not stylized items in IE</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally quite like the flash. It lets me know a new page has actually loaded. It’s feedback.

An old colleague introduced me to a little-known Internet Explorer `<meta>` tag... thing that lets you do, amongst other things, a [fade transition](http://jansfreeware.com/articles/ie-page-transitions.html) between pages, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(Duration=2)">
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Fade(Duration=2)">
```

It’s IE-only.